# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column

Tags: android, json, gson

im learning parcing and got a problem trying to make it happen.
found a lot of similar questions and more solutions but nothing helped me

thats my json

```
{
  "firstName": "name",
  "lastName": "last",
  "resistances": {
    "a1": 1,
    "a2": 2,
    "a3": 3,
    "a4": 4
  }
}
```

Player.class

```
class Player implements Serializable{

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int[] resistances;

    public Player(String firstName, String lastName, int[] resistances) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.resistances = resistances;
    }
}
```

and how i try to parce

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Player player = gson.fromJson("test.json", Player.class);
```

SOS

Comment: the third variable will be an object.. resistances..

Comment: and the outermost json pbj must have a name..

Comment: For "resistances" to be an array it should be:
    "resistances": [
        1, 2, 3, 4
    ]
so the error message is because it is finding the string "a1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fromJson(String, Class)](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) parses the String itself, in your case `test.json`, not the file it represents. You need to create a Reader from the file you are trying to parse and pass it as first argument.

If test.json is in the external storage:

```
String fpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/test.json";
 try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fpath));
        gson.fromJson(fr, Player.class);
} catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I would have done this from the beginning, but it depends on the location of your file. If `test.json` is in the `raw` resource folder you can use `new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test))` (the extension is ignored). If it's on the sd card, the answer is a bit longer.

Comment: thank you very much! its working! one more question - what is the difference between putting .json file is assets folder or raw ?

Comment: Here is an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563373/the-reason-for-assets-and-raw-resources-in-android

Comment: tyvm again! can i give you +karma ? :D

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON "resistances" object should look like this for your parsing code to work:

```
{
  "firstName": "name",
  "lastName": "last",
  "resistances": [
    1, 2, 3, 4
  ]
}
```

Or, change the resistances variable in Java to a Map. [Look here for a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6363524/5774498) - GSON can parse a dictionary JSON object to a Map.

```
class Player implements Serializable {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Map<String, Integer> resistances;

    public Player(String firstName, String lastName, Map<String, Integer> resistances) {
        this.firstName   = firstName;
        this.lastName    = lastName;
        this.resistances = resistances;
    }
}
```